# PostgreSQL equivalent to MongoDB's Mongoose?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, postgresql, mongoose

I'm using PostgreSQL for a project , and for that I need a SQL database.

Anyone knows what's PostgreSQL equivalent to MongoDB's Mongoose ?

Answer (score 5):

you can try Sequelize for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are coding in. Mongoose is an ODM or object data modelling tool for Node.js.

Those object modelling tools are typically tied to a particular language or framework. In Java, one might use Hibernate. In Django, there is a custom ORM (swap data for relational). With Node, one might use a tool like Sequalize.

Sequalize is probably the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to convert JSONB typed columns into objects that you can load update and save like you do using mongoose:

The § "JSONB (PostgreSQL only)" type in the [sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/other-data-types.html) will show you how.

[node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/features/types) might be an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article denoting some other ORM options for. JS: https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/database-tools/top-nodejs-orms-query-builders-and-database-libraries#prisma

In short:

1. Sequelize (Most popular))
2. Knex.js
3. Bookshelf.js
4. Objection.js
5. TypeORM (TypeScript)